# Howto save the Target Platform in a VisualStudio Solution (with version control and testing in mind)

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, build-process, target-platform

Visual Studio (at least VisualStudio 2010) stores the target platform settings in the `*.suo` file which obviously shall not be version controlled.

In my case this is no problem for the central build because that uses a command line option on msbuild that force the target platform to be x86 as required.

However, if a colleague checks out my project he will always end up building for AnyCPU and testing that. Because he has no `*.suo` file VisualStudio will use the default settings.

Bad or not, the colleague is obliged to test for x86.

Is there an **easy** way to safely persist the target platform for a Solution? An environment variable forcing the default is not exactly what we need but would be good enough and easy enough.

Comment: `*.suo?` Isn't this information in the project file (for ex. `*.csproj`)?

`<PropertyGroup>
   <Platform>x86</Platform>
</PropertyGroup>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Visual Studio ... stores the target platform settings in the *.suo file

It doesn't, it stores it in the project file.  A relevant snippet from one I created:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    // etc...
  </PropertyGroup>
```

It is configured with Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target combo box.  Repeat for the Release configuration.  Only the setting on the EXE project matters, that's the one that determines the bitness for the process.  DLLs have no choice and ought to use AnyCPU.

---

In all likelihood you are being tripped up by a rather drastic design mistake in VS2010.  Another item is the solution platform name, prominently displayed in the Build + Configuration Manager dialog for example.  This was always AnyCPU for managed projects, VS2010 screwed this up royally by renaming the default to "x86".  And creating a big old mess of it when you import projects from earlier versions, yielding a "Mixed platforms" configuration.  And yes, the last selection is saved in the .suo file.

This is irrelevant to managed projects, it only matters to C++ projects.  Where the setting selects a different set of build tools.  The 64-bit compiler and linker are different programs.  A non-existing issue for managed projects, bitness is determined at runtime by the jitter selection and you use the exact same C# compiler regardless of the desired platform target.

The best way to eliminate these kind of mistakes is by aggressively deleting platforms and only keeping one.  Use Build + Configuration Manager, select the "Edit" entry in the upper-right combo box and click Remove for extraneous platforms until you only have AnyCPU left.  Updating your VS version is also recommended, this mistake was corrected again in VS2012.

Comment: Not easy to verify for me because it is about a problem I create for others but do not experience myself. *drastic mistake* and *this mistake* refer only to renaming the default, right? And the offense is renaming not a changing the default, right? Furthermore I have some intuition of what a project platform is, but what is a Solution platform? +1 for *This is irrelevant to managed projects* because I can reference to this statement. 444k should be convincing enough to discourage opposition.

Comment: "Project platform" doesn't mean anything.  Changing the solution platform selection affects the build of all projects in the solution.  The core problem is that you have multiple solution platform selections and their Project + Properties, Build tab settings do not agree.  You solve it by making sure that a team mate cannot have the wrong selection active.  If there is only one choice then it can never be wrong.  So the VS design mistake refers to VS adding solution platform selections almost randomly outside of your control.  That's bad.

Comment: So *this mistake was corrected again in VS2012* solves my problem. That would qualify as easy solution because I just have to wait a few days until we migrate to VS2012 anyway. I will believe it without testing 8-)